# How to configure unity container to provide string constructor value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

This is my **`dad`** class

```
 public class Dad
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;set;
        }
        public Dad(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

This is my test method

```
public void TestDad()
        {
           UnityContainer DadContainer= new UnityContainer();
           Dad newdad = DadContainer.Resolve<Dad>();    
           newdad.Name = "chris";    
           Assert.AreEqual(newdad.Name,"chris");                 
        }
```

This is the error I am getting

```
"InvalidOperationException - the type String cannot be constructed.
 You must configure the container to supply this value"
```

How do I configure my `DadContainer` for this assertion to pass?
Thank you

Comment: Take a look at constructor injection. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should provide a parameterless constructor:

```
public class Dad
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Dad()
    {
    }

    public Dad(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

If you can't provide a parameterless constructor, you need to configure the container to provide it, either by directly registering it with the container:

```
UnityContainer DadContainer = new UnityContainer();
DadContainer.RegisterType<Dad>(
    new InjectionConstructor("chris"));
```

or through the app/web.config file:

```xml
<configSections>
  <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
</configSections>

<unity>
  <containers>
    <container>
      <register type="System.String, MyProject">
        <constructor>
          <param name="name" value="chris" />
        </constructor>
      </register >
    </container>
  </containers>
</unity>
```

Comment: its as simple as that? LOL  ... but what if I can't and the constructor must have a string parameter?( for some reason that I can't think of right now)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: You can definitely use an `InjectionConstructor` to supply the name.  However, that will always use the same name for all `Dad` instances.  If you want a different value you can use a ResolverOverride: `DadContainer.Resolve<Dad>(new ParameterOverride("name", nameOfDad));`

Answer (score -1):

10 Years later and I've just stumbled upon this same challenge.
A lot of people ask this question (or a very similar question on SO) but there are few answers and none that are as direct as what I found in the Unity documentation.

**Solution Discovery**

I too had a class that needed a string passed in upon construction.

The answer is actually quite simple, but somewhat confusing.

Here's the answer from [UnityContainer.org](http://unitycontainer.org/articles/quickstart.html) * *with my alterations to refer to the OP's class (instead of the sample class used by the docs)*.

> `Dad` is a simple class with [one] public constructors. When
> Resolve() is called, Unity will evaluate available constructors
> **and select one with longest list of parameters it can satisfy with dependencies**. It will create all required dependencies and pass them
> to selected constructor during initialization.
>
> In this particular case Unity will select [available] constructor with
> parameter `name` of type `String`.  However, constructor `Dad(string name)` has parameter of type `String` which is a primitive type.
> **Unity can not create primitive types by itself**. If you want to make these available for dependency injection **you would need to
> register them with the container**.

```
// Register string instance
container.RegisterInstance("Frank");

// Resolve Dad
container.Resolve<Dad>();
```

That's it!

However, I'm not sure what happens if you have more than one type with a constructor which requires a string.
How do you know which string will be used with which constructor?