# Using two different databases with my model - crash on constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, datacontext

I have a project that works for a single database.  Now I need to get it to work with a second (within the same project) that has the same data structure.  So I am using the same model and am trying to pass in the Data Connection name upon calling my Data Context Class.  Unfortunately I am receiving the following error:

> The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the
>   container to supply this value.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
public UniversityContext(string context)
            : base(context){

   }
```

When I looked for answers I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391122/how-to-configure-unity-container-to-provide-string-constructor-value) answer for that error and it recommends, having a parameter-less constructor as well.  I tried that and still the same issue.

Here it is with the parameter-less constructor:

```
public UniversityContext()
            : base("UniversityConnection")
        {

        }

        public UniversityContext(string context)
            : base(context)
        {

        }
```

In case it matters I am using Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Unity automatically tries to use the most greedy constructor. In your case this is:

```
public UniversityContext(string context)
```

You can configure this with an injection constructor, without seeing your code something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<UniversityContext>(
          new InjectionConstructor("UniversityContext"));
```

Comment: Hutchonoid, thank you for your response but where would I put the injection constructor?  And how do I get it ti change depending on the different connection.  Btw, I updated the original post a little (updated the connection name).

Comment: @djblois No problem, I usually have a bootstrapper that configures all the registered types. You could read the value in from web.config or determine it at runtime depending on your requirements. This is a good article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396